# How to create list based on two different columns of an entity using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-8

Not able to share actual class so sharing some similar kind of scenario.

**Description:**

Entity Name: Employee

Columns: name, nickname, etc...

- Allow null in name and nickname.

Action:

- Input: List< Employee >
- Output: List< String >. (Contain name & nickname)
- Must use stream class and generate a list.
- Have to check null condition on both columns. If not null then only you have to put them in our final list.
- In short, I have to perform a null base filter on columns 'name' and 'nickname' on a list of Employees and create a List of String.

Comment: you can at least share your attempt to the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways you can get expected result

```
        List<String> nameNickNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> combinedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        // add all names to nameNickNameList 
        empList.stream().filter( e -> (nameNickNameList.add(e.getName()) )).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
        // add all nickNames to nameNickNameList 
        empList.stream().filter( e -> (nameNickNameList.add(e.getNickName()) )).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // filter out non null values and assign to combinedList 
        combinedList = nameNickNameList.stream().filter(s -> (s!=null) && !s.trim().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        for(String s : combinedList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Input: empList has

```
        Employee e1 = new Employee("James","Jimmy", 20.5);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("Robert",null, 25.5);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("Kevin","Kev", 12.0);
        Employee e4 = new Employee("David","", 16.0);
        Employee e5 = new Employee("Alexander","Alex", 5.0);
```

Output

```
James
Robert
Kevin
David
Alexander
Jimmy
Kev
Alex
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, But I already placed a solution using the classic for loop method. I already try this way also, But It takes too much line of code. I want to implement same functionality in single flow using Stream API(If possible).